# Bash scripting FS use

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a command which finds and prints the filenames, but I am having a problem understanding the part "FS=/ <(find)" . The full command is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$NF in a' FS=, data.txt FS=/ <(find)
```

And the output is:

```
  user>./test.sh data.txt
./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3
./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3
./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3
```

Why does it output every file 3 times? I want only one time, because there is only file1 file2 file3. And the content of data.txt is:

```
user>cat data.txt
dir1,file2,2018/07/04,2009/10/12 10:45,john
dir3,file1,2018/07/04,2005/08/07 13:57,john
dir3,file3,2018/07/04,2006/10/14 09:56,john
```

Comment: What's the output of `find`? Is it `./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your reply. On my system yes, I have `./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3` . But the script is showing me three times each dir and file.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the issue.

I created a directory which contains 3 subdirectories (test1, test2, test3) and 3 files (./test1/file1 ./test2/file2 ./test3/file3) + the data.txt file

`find` returns :

```
user> find
.
./test2
./test2/file2
./test1
./test1/file1
./test3
./test3/file3
./data.txt
```

I'll try to explain the awk command :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$NF in a' FS=, data.txt FS=/ <(find)
```

awk is reading from file data.txt and `find` output, using `,` as separator for data.txt and `/` separator for `find` output.

awk command is equivalent to :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2] = 1}NR!=FNR{if($NF in a){print $0}}' FS=, data.txt FS=/ <(find)
```

which means :

```
for rows in data.txt:
    store second column in array
for file (or dir) in current_directory:
    if name of file in array:
        print path of file
```

On my system, this command returns what I expected :

```
./test2/file2
./test1/file1
./test3/file3
```

May you add to your question the exact output of the find command ? I assume that the command does not return the files in the proper format on your system (1 line per file or directory)